# How to set Audio alert in Google spreadsheet that triggers by a specific value?

Tags: google-sheets

Can I set an Audio alert in a Google spreadsheet cell that triggers whenever it changes a specific value?

I want some thing similar to "beepnow" function which is using in MS Excel VBA.

Comment: An interesting question. It seems possible per [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26787820).

Comment: Thanks http://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/79865/normal-human.i am not a programmer,i want this audio alert in a particular cell when its triggerd.How to insert this function in a cell

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

At this time it's not possible to trigger an audio alert through an on edit event without opening and HTML sidebar or dialog.

## Explanation

The equivalent to Excel VBA is [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start) which is based on JavaScript. Unfortunately they don't include a class for sounds.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26787820/1595451) by Mogsdad to the referred [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26787820) in a comment by [user 79865](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/79865/) use the audio tag from HTML5, that could be used in an HTML side bar or dialog but not alone.